# Make apt-get (or aptitude) run with -y but not prompt for replacement of configuration files?

Tags: apt, aptitude

When running `apt-get -y install <packages ...>` on Ubuntu 10.04 I would like `apt-get` (or `aptitude` if that makes it easier) to not prompt me when installing additional dependencies (behavior of `-y` as I understand it) and but **not** prompt me about overwriting configuration files, instead assume to keep the existing ones always (which is usually the default). Unfortunately `--trivial-only` seems to be the inverse of `-y` and not affect the prompt that is shown, according to the `man` page.

In particular packages auch as `samba`, `nullmailer`, `localepurge` and `lighttpd` have forced me to interact with the terminal, even though the whole procedure was scripted and meant to be non-interactive.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You may use:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" dist-upgrade
```

For only specific packages, e.g. mypackage1 mypackage2:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" install mypackage1 mypackage2
```

Source: http://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/09/21/debian-conffile-configuration-file-managed-by-dpkg/

```
Avoiding the conffile prompt

Every time that dpkg must install a new conffile that you have modified
(and a removed file is only a particular case of a modified file in dpkg’s eyes),
it will stop the upgrade and wait your answer. This can be particularly annoying for
major upgrades. That’s why you can give predefined answers to dpkg with the help
of multiple --force-conf* options:

    --force-confold: do not modify the current configuration file, the new version
is installed with a .dpkg-dist suffix. With this option alone, even configuration
files that you have not modified are left untouched. You need to combine it with
--force-confdef to let dpkg overwrite configuration files that you have not modified.
    --force-confnew: always install the new version of the configuration file, the
current version is kept in a file with the .dpkg-old suffix.
    --force-confdef: ask dpkg to decide alone when it can and prompt otherwise. This
is the default behavior of dpkg and this option is mainly useful in combination with
--force-confold.
    --force-confmiss: ask dpkg to install the configuration file if it’s currently
missing (for example because you have removed the file by mistake).

If you use Apt, you can pass options to dpkg with a command-line like this:

$ apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" dist-upgrade

You can also make those options permanent by creating /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/local:

Dpkg::Options {
   "--force-confdef";
   "--force-confold";
}
```

You can find more information and more options in the dpkg manual at http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dpkg.1.html or `man dpkg` and i.e. look for "confdef".

Comment: "I believe this is self-explanatory" ... proceeds to use options I've never seen anyone use for apt-get

Comment: @notbad.jpeg: I believe the remark was aimed at the naming of those options. I find the names indeed self-explanatory. Of course knowing to use them wasn't :-D

Comment: I'd think they're mutually exclusive (force default vs force old), and don't understand why you'd specify both ...

Comment: @tink, no `--force-confold` and `--force-confnew` are mutually exclusive. In some cases (I'm not too sure when, though) there may not be a clear default action to be taken so `--force-confdef` would not know what to do. In such cases, the `--force-confold` is chosen. The default, though, can be to install the new configuration file which I know a server has done in the past because some options were wrong (unsecure) so instead of letting you use the wrong information, by default they overwrote your file... (they made a backup first though.)

Comment: what about `-y` ?

Comment: See also: https://linux.die.net/man/1/dpkg under the `--force` section, it describes the `confold` and `confdef` options.  Also helpful: `apt-config dump` from https://askubuntu.com/questions/254129/how-to-display-all-apt-get-dpkgoptions-and-there-current-values

Comment: "self-explanatory"... hmm, I found that description extremely confusing, especially whether to use them in combination or not. The one that cleared things up was `dpkg(1)`. Thanks @thom_nic.

Comment: Answer updated as per the comments :)

Comment: The seems to be contradictions between http://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/09/21/debian-conffile-configuration-file-managed-by-dpkg/ and http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dpkg.1.html about the behavior or using `confdef` and `confold` together. At the very least, the docs are confusing, and I think it best that someone clarify by editing this answer.

Comment: For now, can someone confirm that I'm interpreting the following point correctly?  When `confold` and `confdef` are used concurrently, it means: "overwrite conf files that have not changed (if the upgraded pkg has a new one), and keep the ones that have (changed)."