# Configuring grub-efi dialog during regular update

Tags: grub2, updates, 22.04, grub-efi

I had to restart my pihole server which is running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS after about 6 months or so. It rebooted and offered updates. I clicked Yes, entered password and the update began as usual. Half way through I'm presented with screen attached below, which doesn't tell me what it wants or why, but insists on me selecting the only option it gives me. If I don't it cycles back and asks again, if I do, it warns me that it can wreak havok.

- What is this?
- How do I proceed?
- (personal) how is this considered in any way, shape or form the correct way to do anything, I mean this is supposed to be human-friendly distro and it casually presents danger-zone dialogs with zero instruction on what it wants from me or how to correctly continue. It's 23:28, I want to go to bed and I just wanted to install updates.

[image: Ubuntu update asking me about something grub related]

Comment: What happened to the disk? Why has its unique identifier changed? (Or why is it missing?) Did you move about / swap some disks?

Comment: Also, possibly this part will not be as human-friendly as hoped. In other words, you may have to learn to reinstall `grub` (Which is the Grand Unified Boot Loader, a citically important software.) By putting part of the message into a web search, I found these threads: https://askubuntu.com/q/1134349 and https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2065633 Before you reinstall anything, you could explain us how did you install the OS in the first place, and also about what might have happened to the disk; so that you don't repeat that mistake in the upcoming reinstall.

Comment: This appears to be a brute-force approach which does not attempt to solve anything, rather takes the risks and proceeds by bypassing those dialogs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26852572

Comment: Here's a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1872100

Comment: Your sda1 says it is an ESP - efi system partition. That should be the partition referred to in your `cat /etc/fstab`. Compare UUID of sda1 `lsblk -f` May be easier to use Boot-Repair. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: This another bug report might be more insightful? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1872077

Comment: I keep snapshots of the volume this VM is running from, so I flipped the table and tried selecting the option and continuing. The dialog is basically broken, it matters not if I select the option or not, on the next page I have to confirm that I do not wish to pick grub bootloader, regardless if I selected one on the previous screen or not. I had to reconfirm once more that I know what I'm doing (I had no clue) and it just continued. Keep in mind this is stock install from their image with pihole installed on it. That's it. I didn't move or swap disks, nor did I change any identifiers.