# How to disable interactive dialogs in Ubuntu 1604 and 1804?

Tags: command-line, apt, sudo

I found this [question](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/1139/how-to-avoid-interactive-dialogs-when-running-apt-get-upgrade-y-in-ubuntu-16?newreg=2cd90db0d9e6416db29ae4e46c0dbb71) and basically had the same problem with my script.

But! I am not running it with packer but with a simple script:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive sudo apt-get update
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive sudo dpkg --configure -aq
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive sudo apt-get upgrade -yq --force-yes
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -yq --force-yes
```

...and other things.

The script did work on 1404, but with 1604 Xenial and 1804 Bionic I am getting the problem, that the dialog prompt wants to open in the script and doesn't continue on his own. This is because I can't respond with keyboard inputs on the workstation.

[This solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146921/how-do-i-apt-get-y-dist-upgrade-without-a-grub-config-prompt/262445#262445) seems to be too risky for GRUB in my opinion, but I need to automate because I can't update hundreds of servers manually.

I think this is a problem for all "new" 1604 and 1804 machines.

Does anybody know a solution for this?

Update: I trie [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104899/make-apt-get-or-aptitude-run-with-y-but-not-prompt-for-replacement-of-configu) accepted answer solution and it gave me the following error:

```
E: Invalid operation Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef
```

Comment: *"I am getting the problem very often"* what problem, exactly? FWIW I would expect the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` assignment to go **after** `sudo`, not before

Comment: I am getting the problem, that the dialog prompt wants to open in the script and doesn't continue on his own. This is because I can't respond with keyboard inputs on the workstation. The dialog is prompting on the server.

Comment: @steeldriver I am testing your remark now and put the DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive after the sudo and it seems that it does the trick. I thank you very much for this comment. It seems that this is the little thing that hindered my script from working.

Comment: Shall I post the solution as an answer or do you want to do it? Then I can mark it as accepted. Damn, you just saved me precious hours! I am very glad. Thank you!

Comment: This is more general than Ubuntu and a more comprehensive answer is on https://serverfault.com/questions/227190/how-do-i-ask-apt-get-to-skip-any-interactive-post-install-configuration-steps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` inside the `sudo` environment - not before it:

Ex.

```
$ sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive sh -c 'echo $DEBIAN_FRONTEND'
noninteractive
```

whereas

```
$ DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive sudo sh -c 'echo $DEBIAN_FRONTEND'
(empty)
```